# First order linear differential equation.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I'm trying to solve
$$
y'(x)+x^2y(x)=3x^3+5x^2+3.
$$

The standard formula 
$$
y(x)=e^{A(x)}\int e^{-A(x)}b(x)dx
$$
where $a(x)=-x^2$, $A(x)$ is such that $A(x)'=a(x)$ and $b(x)=3x^3+5x^2+3$,
yields
$$
y(x)=e^{-x^3/3}\int e^{x^3/3}(3x^3+5x^2+3)dx
$$
for which I'm struggling to come up with a solution.

Comment: no elementary solution

Comment: @Vladimir: Integrating Factor?

Comment: @Moo What do you mean?

Comment: If you use an IF, this is solvable.

Comment: Note that $y_0(x)=3x+5$ is a particular solution...

Answer (score 1):

$$I_1=\int e^{x^3/3} 5x^2 dx= \int e^t 5 dt=5 e^t=5e^{t^3/3}$$ 
$$I_2=\int e^{x^3/3}(3x^3+3) dx=\int x~~3x^2 e^{x^3/3}+3\int e^{x^3/3} dx$$ $$\implies I_2=x \int 3x^2 e^{x^3/3} dx-\int 1. 3 e^{x^3/3}+3 \int e^{x^3/3}dx$$
$$\implies I_2=3xe^{x^3/3}.$$
So finally $$I=I_1+I_2=(3x+5)e^{x*3/3}$$.
Lastly, $$y(x)=(3x+5)+Ce^{-x^3/3}$$